# Disable keyboard when UITextfield is changed

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have checked every possible thread before posting this question but couldn't find a good solution.

I have 5 textfields in my view, when selected the first 2 a keyboard should appear and when selected the last 3 my PickerView should appear. Everything works fine as I have used tags to identify my textfields and in the "textFieldShouldBeginEditing" I returned False for my last 3 textfields.

HOWEVER if I selected text field 2 and then move to text field 3,keyboard will appear OVER the picker view. 
I have tried using textFieldDidEndEditing but it didn't work.

Is there any other approaches to solve this problem?

I use addTarget on each textfield to call this function

```
func openDatesPicker() {

    ActionSheetStringPicker.show(withTitle: "Appointment Date", rows: datesArray , initialSelection: selectedDateIndex , doneBlock: {
        picker, value, index in
        self.selectedDateIndex = value
        if let selected = index as? String{
            self.dateTF.text = selected
            let timeIndex = self.findEarliestTime(date: self.dateTF.text!)
            self.timeTF.text = timeIndex

        }

        return
    }, cancel: { ActionStringCancelBlock in return }, origin: self.view)

}
```

Comment: How are you showing the picker views?

Comment: Im using a custom picker viewer i found on GitHub , its called "ActionSheetPicker_3_0"

Comment: But how are you showing the picker view? What makes it appear on the screen?

Comment: I updated my question @rmaddy

Comment: Have you tried using resignFirstResponder() ?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work @user1000

Comment: Where did you call resignFirstResponder method?

Comment: I tried it in "textFieldShouldReturn" and "textFieldDidEndEditing" @user1000

Comment: Please add this statement in the beginning of your openDatesPicker method  self.view.endEditing(true) and then run the program again

Comment: THANK YOU !!!!!! It worked !!!! I tried "self.view.endEditing(true)" in my startEditing but didn't work, I added to my openDatesPicker and it worked. Thank you very much @user1000

Comment: I accepted it as the answer. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help, please read the answer so you could understand how it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this statement in the beginning of your openDatesPicker method

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

According to documentation:

> This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for
>   the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one,
>   it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force
>   parameter is set to true, the text field is never even asked; it is
>   forced to resign.

Answer (score 0):

just set last 3 textfields  inputView as pickerView .No need to returned False or do different code for last 3 textfields.It will work fine.

```
 textfield.inputView = pickerView
```

Comment: The problem is that i don't have a pickerView. Im using a custom PickerView and it doesn't have a view variable